# Derivation of rotation matrices in A. Zee's Einstein gravity in a nutshell

Tags: group-theory, rotation, lie-algebra

In page-40 of A. Zee's Einstein Gravity book, rotations are generated by considering the powers of the infinitesimal rotation given as:

$$ R( \theta) \approx I+A$$
Now, he to establish the form of $A$, he uses the property that:

$$ R(\theta) \cdot R^T =  I \tag{1}$$

Where $I$ is identity matrix because before he had defined rotation matrices as those matrices which follow the two properties:

> 1. Orthogonality : $R^T R =I$
> 2. Special $det(R)$ =1

My doubt is in the simplification of (1), here is the algebra done in the book:

$$ (I+A) ( I^T + A^T) = I$$

Simplifying LHS:

$$ I+A^T + A =I$$

Cancelling, we find $A=-A^T$ and apparently there is only one matrix A solving this.

---

**Here are my questions on the above derivation:**

1. Why is $AA^T=0$?
2. Why is the matrix satisfying the equation $A^T=-A$ unique?

Comment: For a $D$ dimensional matrix, a general anti-symmetric matrix is a linear combination of $D(D-1)/2$ independent "basis matrices." As you can see, in $D=1$ there are no antisymmetric matrices, and for $D=2$ (ie for 2x2 matrices) there is only one independent antisymmetric matrix (which is also kind of obvious if you think about it), but for $D>2$ there is not a unique antisymmetric matrix. Is your book working in the case $D=2$? (This would correspond to rotations in a plane).

Comment: Yeah in the section here it's D=2, he writes at end of the chapter that in D=3, there are 3 diff matrices for generating rotations @Andrew

Comment: got it, thanks.

Comment: or... another way of phrasing things is to say that you're considering a smooth curve $\gamma$ in the orthogonal group through the origin such  (i.e so that $\gamma(0)=I$ and for all $s$, $\gamma(s)^T\gamma(s)=I$). Then, differentiating this at $s=0$ using product rule yields $\gamma(0)^T\dot{\gamma}(0)+\dot{\gamma}(0)^T\gamma(0)=0$, or simplifying (recall that $\gamma(0)=I$) we get $\dot{\gamma}(0)^T=-\dot{\gamma}(0)$. In fancier words, this is a calculation of the tangent space at the identity of the orthogonal group $T_I(O(n))$. (the "special"-ness doesn't add any new conditions to $A$).

Comment: A is a skew symmetric matrix thus $A^T=-A$ and $-A\,A\approx 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you wrote in the beginning, $R \approx I + A$. For rotations in a plane, the [full expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Lie_theory)) is $R = e^A$. So the book is working to linear order in $A$, and therefore drops terms that are $O(A^2)$.
2. A general $D\times D$ matrix has $D^2$ parameters. To count the number of *antisymmetric* matrices, we only count matrix entries **below** the diagonal (since elements on the diagonal have to be zero by antisymmetry, and the anti-symmetry relates elements below the diagonal to elements above the diagonal). For $D=2$, there is $1$ element below the diagonal; for $D=3$ there are $1+2$ elements; for $D=4$ there are $1+2+3=6$ elements; and in general one gets a sequence of [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), so in $D$ dimensions there are $D(D-1)/2$ parameters. Since your book is working in $D=2$, there is one parameter for an antisymmetric matrix. This parameter is the angle of rotation.

Comment: The book mentioned also mentioned only terms of order $A^2$ survive but is $A^T\cdot A $ of order $A^2$? How can one conclde this?

Comment: @Buraian Write out an 2 dimensional antisymmetric matrix -- there is one parameter, we can call it $\theta$. Working to linear order in $A$ means working to linear order in $\theta$. If you multiply out $A A^T$, you will find that all the matrix elements are either 0 or order $\theta^2$, there are no terms which involve $\theta^1$.

Comment: Ah right so the idea is that $O(A^2)$ means the matrix entries are of order of $\theta^2$ and since here it the product matrix has entries of $\theta^2$ , it is of order $O(A^2)$. Thanks!

Comment: @Buraian a lot of times you will see people separate the parameters from the "generators" (matrices) to make this more explicit. For example, let $i \sigma_y$ be the matrix with (0,1) on the top row and (-1,0) on the bottom row (so $i \sigma_y$ is antisymmetric). Note that $\sigma_y$ is a Pauli matrix. Often people will write $A=i \theta \sigma_y$, and say they are working to linear order in $\theta$ (instead of $A$), that is a bit more explicit and separates the parameter describing the rotation from the "generator" (matrix structure).